# Azure AD B2C custom policy logic flow overview?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm trying to better understand the custom policy/Identity Experience Framework within Azure AD B2C.  There is a lot of how-to for specific scenarios in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) and I've already gotten great answers to specific problems on this site, but I am still struggling to see the **whole picture**.

Is anyone aware of a resource that explains the process/logic flow at a higher level, to help me understand how the `UserJourneys`, `ClaimsProviders`, and other components actually interact?

thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation can be found in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/Documentation). This was drafted for the custom policies preview (known as the "Azure AD B2C Premium" service when this was written). Some of it is out-of-date but it does describe the high-level concepts and details the custom policy schema.

Comment: Thanks @Chris.  I found [Part 6](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md]) most helpful.